# Bootstrap styled radio button auto post back not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue regarding bootstrap and asp.net radio button. Namely, the 'AutoPostBack' command is not working. The code:

Bootsrap & JS Files Linked:

```
<link href="css/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script> 
<link href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Radio Button:

```
  <label class ="btn btn-default">
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbAllSites" runat="server" GroupName="SiteOfManu"  Checked="false"  Text="All Sites" AutoPostBack="true"  OnCheckedChanged="rdbAllSites_CheckedChanged" />
  </label>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have set AutoPostBack to true so expect a post back to the server. However, this does not work and I have no idea why. Note however that if I dont apply any bootstrap to the radio buttons, they do in fact postback.

Is there something I'm missing?

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you us the complete code of how you add the bootstrap to your control? Js code, CSS code, ...

Comment: Hi, Did You manage to solve the issue ??

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code, And it worked fine!

```
 <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
     <label class ="btn btn-default">
     <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbCurrentSite" runat="server" GroupName="SiteOfManu"   Checked="true" OnCheckedChanged="rd1"  Autopostback="true" Text="Current Site"  /> 
     </label>

     <label class ="btn btn-default">
       <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbAllSites" runat="server" GroupName="SiteOfManu"  Checked="false"  Text="All Sites" AutoPostBack="true"  OnCheckedChanged="rd2" />
    </label>
    </div>
```

C# file contains these two methods

```
protected void rd1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Response.Write("Radio1 Clicked");

}

protected void rd2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Response.Write("Radio2  Clicked");

}
```

vb.net

```
    Protected Sub rd1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles rdbAllSites.CheckedChanged
        Response.Write("Button 1")
    End Sub

  Protected Sub rd2(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles rdbAllSites.CheckedChanged
        Response.Write("Button 2")
    End Sub
```

Please try this! and let us know whether it worked or not.

Thank you!

Comment: I tried your exact code (in a VB file tho) and it doesnt seem to work for me. Clicking on the radio buttons does not trigger any postback :/ .

Comment: u can't use exact C# code in vb file! I have updated my answer which consists of VB codes! i am not expert in VB, but i manage to write this code successfully! Both c# and vb code working! Please check and lemme know if you still face issue. Thank you @SabeloNgcobo